# How to look into a list and varify the existing of elements inside the list?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to write a piece of code which has accomplishes task:

- I need to open the file romeo.txt and read it line by line.
- For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() function. * * Build a list of words as follows:

  - For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list
  - If not append it to the list.
- When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order.

You can download the sample data at http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/romeo.txt

This is what I have so far:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) == 0:
    fname = open('romeo.txt')
newList = []
for line in fname:
    words = line.rstrip().split()

    print words
```

I know that I need to use another `for` loop to check for any missing words and finally I need to sort them out by using the `sort()` function.  The Python interpreter is giving me an error saying that I have to use `append()` to add the missing words if they don't exist.

I have managed to build the following list with my code:

```
['But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'breaks'] ←      Mismatch
['It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun']
['Arise', 'fair', 'sun', 'and', 'kill', 'the', 'envious', 'moon']
['Who', 'is', 'already', 'sick', 'and', 'pale', 'with', 'grief']
```

but the output should come look like this:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks','east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick','soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

How can I adjust my code to produce that output?

**Important Note:**
To everyone wants to help, Please make sure that you go from my code to finish this tast as it's an assignment and  we have to follow the level of the course. Thanks

That is my updates for the code :

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) == 0:
    fname = open('romeo.txt')
newList = list()
for line in fname:
    words = line.rstrip().split()
    for i in words:
        newList.append(i) 
        newList.sort()



print newList
```

['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'is', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'sun', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
But I'm getting duplication! Why is that and how to avoide that?

Comment: If you **have** to use `for` loop because of some requirements, please, note this in the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking us to complete his assignment without any insight or understanding from the OP.

Comment: Hello  thebjorn !!!!! I think I know what I'm doing, please read my question with latest update, I'm very close , I just need to know why I'm having duplication ! thats it !

Answer (score 1):

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(frame)
lst = list()
for line in fh
    for i in line.split():
        lst.append(i)
lst.sort()
print list(set(lst))
```

The above code worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ") #Ask the user for the filename.
fh = open(fname)                   #Open the file.
lst = list()                       #Create a list called lst.
for line in fh:                    #For each line in the fh?
     words = line.split() .        #Separate the words in the line.
     for word in words :           #For each word in words.
         if word not in lst :      #If word not in the lst.
            lst.append(word)       #Add the word.
     elif word in lst :            #Continue looping.
        continue
lst.sort()
print(lst)                         #Print the lst.
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this question for quite a long time while i was doing a Online Python course in Coursera. But i managed to do it without too many nested loops or for loops. Hope this helps.

```
file = input('Enter File Name: ')
try:
    file = open(file)
except:
    print('File Not Found')
    quit()
F = file.read()
F = F.rstrip().split()
L = list()
for a in F:
    if a in L:
        continue
    else:
        L.append(a)
print(sorted(L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final_list = list()
file_name = input('Enter file: ')
try:
    file_handle = open(file_name)
    for line in file_handle:
        words = line.rstrip().split()
        for word in words:
            if final_list.__contains__(word):
                continue
            else:
                final_list.append(word)
    final_list = sorted(final_list)
    print(final_list)
except:
    print('Can not open file.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to gather all of the words into a single list. Or, uh, a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), because sets enforce uniqueness and you don't care about order anyways.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) == 0: fname = 'romeo.txt')
with open(fname, 'r') as f: # Context manager
    words = set()
    for line in f: words.update(line.rstrip().split())
#Now for the sorting
print sorted(words, key = str.lower)
```

I'm using `key = str.lower` because I assume you want to sort by human alphabetical and not by computer alphabetical. If you want computer alphabetical, get rid of that argument.

Now, if you actually want to use a list, although it's O(n) for this application...

```
words = []
with open(filename, "r") as f:
   for word in line.rstrip().split():
       if word not in words:
           words.append(word)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , Although I tried your code and it didn't work for me and also, Please make sure that you go from my code to finish this tast as it's an assignment and we have to follow the level of the course.  I just need to use another for loop to check for missing words and then sort them out .

Comment: Please check this error after adding your code starting with words[] :         http://i.gyazo.com/4f196dd2601210eb055493c7071afcf8.png

Comment: and this is an update :   http://i.gyazo.com/2305e2ea86790c09fc371c9bddca6582.png

Answer (score 0):

The 'Pythonic' way is to use a set to make a list of unique words and to interate  over the file line-by-line:

```
with open(fn) as f:    # open your file and auto close it
    uniq=set()         # a set only has one entry of each
    for line in f:     # file line by line
        for word in line.split():    # line word by word
            uniq.add(word)           # uniqueify by adding to a set

print sorted(uniq)     # print that sorted
```

Which you can make terse Pythonic by having a set comprehension that flattens the list of lists produced by 1) a list of lines 2) the lines from the file:

```
with open(fn) as f:
    uniq={w for line in f for w in line.split()}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , Although I tried your code and it didn't work for me and also, Please make sure that you go from my code to finish this tast as it's an assignment and we have to follow the level of the course. I just need to use another for loop to check for missing words and then sort them out

Comment: please check this error with your code :  http://i.gyazo.com/8e81807806a050cb506af87f1f8d0a96.png

Comment: It appears that the file is not being successfully opened or that environment for Python is not set up correctly. I suggest just trying to open that file and printing the contents of it. Then go from there.

Comment: Did you read my update ? I think I'm very close , I just need help to find out why I'm getting duplication in my out put !

Answer (score 0):

8.4 Open the file romeo.txt and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order.
You can download the sample data at http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/romeo.txt

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line=line.rstrip()
    a=line.split()
    i=0
    for z in a:
        if z not in lst:
        lst.append(z)
    else:
        continue
lst.sort()
print lst
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
  word=line.rstrip().split()
  for i in word:
        if i in lst:
          continue
        else:
            lst.append(i)
        lst.sort()
print lst
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers. Try to explain how your code solves OP's problem. In particular, OP has asked why duplicates occur in output, and how to avoid this. You make no attempt to answer these questions. Others who find this question may have less experience than you and have difficulty placing your answer in context.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the EXACT SAME Python Online course in Coursera - "Python for everybody" - and It took me 3 days to complete this assignment and come up with the following piece of code. A short recommendation just if you care
 1) Try writing the code exclusively without ANY hint or help - try at least 10 hours 
2) Leave the questions as "Last Resort"
When you don't give up and write the code independently the reward is IMMENSE.

For the following code I used EXCLUSIVELY the materials covered in week 4 for the course

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ") 
fh = open("romeo.txt")
newlist = list ()
for line in fh:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in newlist :
            newlist.append (word)
        elif word in newlist :
            continue
newlist.sort ()
print (newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line=line.rstrip()
    line=line.split()
    for i in line:
        if i in lst:
           continue
        else:
           lst.append(i)

lst.sort()
print (lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    for i in line.split():
        if i not in lst:
            lst.append(i)
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).